# Why is selection sort faster than bubble sort and also how is insertion sort the fastest

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I wrote a program to sort the number from 1 to 1,000,using three different sorts and then measured the time taken by each individual sort.The results were the following:(I wrote my code in python,and time is in seconds,Worst case is the array in descending order and best case is ascending order)

**Worst case**:

- selection sort: timetaken:0.0629999637604
- bubble sort :    timetaken:0.141000032425
- insertion sort : timetaken:0.0460000038147

**Best case**

- selection sort :  timetaken:0.0469999313354
- bubble sort :      timetaken:0.140000104904
- insertion sort :   timetaken:0.047000169754

---

1. Can I know why the best case for insertion sort takes longer than its worst case? Shouldn't it be the opposite?
2. Why is bubble sort's best case more time consuming than selection sort? It should be the opposite since bubble sort's best case time is O(n), right?

Comment: The timing appear a bit short for a good evaluation. Can you repeat the tests with 100000 numbers?

Comment: 1. How do you decide which the best and which the worst case? It might be not ascending/descending for all algorithms. 2. How did you measure the time? Are you sure that your results are accurate enough to judge the efficiency?

Comment: The best/wordt cases are often (always!) pathological cases such as input already ordered, or reversed.

Comment: (1) In this case, your conclusions are probabily correct, however: (2) Before jumping into conclusions about performance, make sure your results are [statistical significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance)

Comment: Show your code, without it we have to take your word that the implementations are correct.

Comment: There definitely seems to be a problem with either your implementation or your approach in timing the observations. You can look at this website to visualize the speed of sorting algorithms for different cases. http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: Why was this even edited, it's clearly a dead question

Comment: If you want answers about your code, then you need to show us your code. We can't tell you why your implementations behave the way they do unless you show us your implementations.